# Swap elements by drag & drop (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have 4 squares represented like the sketch at the bottom. (or pretend there are only 4 squares in [this puzzle demo](http://interface.eyecon.ro/demos/sort_floats.html).) I want to swap any two, horizontally, vertically or diagonally **without** affecting the other two. In the puzzle demo if you swap any two diagonally, like 1 & 4,  some adjacent squares move also which is undesirable.

I was able to do the swap using jQuery's draggable & dropabble. I do the swap in the drop event of the droppable. However the undesirable visual effect is when I drop a square, it reverts and then the switch happens. I don't want the revert to happen. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589606/jquery-draggable-items-lose-their-draggability-after-being-swapped-with-jsfiddle/4589789#4589789) has most of my code.

Any ideas on how to stop the revert from happening or how to use the same puzzle demo but have only the two squares, to & from, swap without having other squares move? (not sure is this is possible with jQuery sortables)

```
 1   2
 3   4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This swap animation plugin](https://web.archive.org/web/20101022181520/http://www.redplugin.com/index.php?mainmenu=2&submenu=5) for jquery might solve your problem nicely.

Comment: This question is over 6 years old. The website I linked to is now gone, but I added a link using wayback machine.