# jQueryUI Draggable element's position not correct inside container is scaled using css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a `div` with id `box-parent` which scales up/down based on Viewport.  Inside are many boxes that each have the `sq-box` class.  When I try to drag those boxes, their positions are not getting set correctly.  I'm trying to swap between boxes.  Is there any way to get the correct positions while moving the boxes?

CSS

```
#box-parent{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:300px;
  margin:40px auto;
  font-size:0;
  transform:scale(1.2);
}

.sq-box{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:20px;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border:1px solid green;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(".sq-box").draggable({
  appendTo: "#box-parent",
  helper: "clone",
  cursor: "move",
  revert: "invalid"
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="box-parent">
  <div class="sq-box">1</div>
  <div class="sq-box">2</div>
  <div class="sq-box">3</div>
  <div class="sq-box">4</div>
  <div class="sq-box">5</div>
  <div class="sq-box">6</div>
  <div class="sq-box">1</div>
  <div class="sq-box">2</div>
  <div class="sq-box">3</div>
  <div class="sq-box">4</div>
  <div class="sq-box">5</div>
  <div class="sq-box">6</div>
  <div class="sq-box">1</div>
  <div class="sq-box">2</div>
  <div class="sq-box">3</div>
  <div class="sq-box">4</div>
  <div class="sq-box">5</div>
  <div class="sq-box">6</div>
  <div class="sq-box">1</div>
  <div class="sq-box">2</div>
  <div class="sq-box">3</div>
  <div class="sq-box">4</div>
  <div class="sq-box">5</div>
  <div class="sq-box">6</div>
</div>
```

Here is a JSFiddle of the issue - https://jsfiddle.net/mhb35rnr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is closer to what you're hoping for.  In order to do what you want you need to use a `draggable` with a `droppable`.  Note the addition of `transform-origin` and `position: absolute` to workaround a jQuery draggable visual artifact when dragging and scaling is applied.

[Working JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5ef2tfoL/)

**CSS**

```
#box-parent{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:300px;
  font-size:0;
  position: absolute;
  transform-origin:top left;
  transform:scale(1.2);
}

.sq-box{
  display:inline-block;
  font-size:20px;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  border:1px solid green;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.ui-state-hover {
  background: lightyellow;   
}

.ui-state-active {
  background: lightgray;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
jQuery.fn.swap = function(b){ 
    // method from: http://blog.pengoworks.com/index.cfm/2008/9/24/A-quick-and-dirty-swap-method-for-jQuery
    b = jQuery(b)[0]; 
    var a = this[0]; 
    var t = a.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(''), a); 
    b.parentNode.insertBefore(a, b); 
    t.parentNode.insertBefore(b, t); 
    t.parentNode.removeChild(t); 
    return this; 
};

$(".sq-box").draggable({
     connectToSortable: "#box-parent",
     cursor: "move",
     revert: "invalid",
     helper: "clone"
});

$(".sq-box").droppable({
    accept: ".sq-box",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {

        var draggable = ui.draggable, droppable = $(this),
            dragPos = draggable.position(), dropPos = droppable.position();

        draggable.css({
            left: dropPos.left+'px',
            top: dropPos.top+'px'
        });

        droppable.css({
            left: dragPos.left+'px',
            top: dragPos.top+'px'
        });
        draggable.swap(droppable);
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="box-parent">
  <div class="sq-box">1</div>
  <div class="sq-box">2</div>
  <div class="sq-box">3</div>
  <div class="sq-box">4</div>
  <div class="sq-box">5</div>
  <div class="sq-box">6</div>
  <div class="sq-box">1</div>
  <div class="sq-box">2</div>
  <div class="sq-box">3</div>
  <div class="sq-box">4</div>
  <div class="sq-box">5</div>
  <div class="sq-box">6</div>
  <div class="sq-box">1</div>
  <div class="sq-box">2</div>
  <div class="sq-box">3</div>
  <div class="sq-box">4</div>
  <div class="sq-box">5</div>
  <div class="sq-box">6</div>
  <div class="sq-box">1</div>
  <div class="sq-box">2</div>
  <div class="sq-box">3</div>
  <div class="sq-box">4</div>
  <div class="sq-box">5</div>
  <div class="sq-box">6</div>
</div>
```

I borrowed some of this from this [existing SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625401/swap-elements-when-you-drag-one-onto-another-using-jquery-ui/7653804)

Comment: Well.. I cannot remove the css transform scale from the `box-parent`. :(

Comment: @XahedKamal, please see the updated answer, it now supports transform scaling.  Had to add transform-origin and position: absolute.