# Drag and Swap with JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need to drag and swap contents from two divs, have tried the following which works fine and swap content into the droppable DIV correctly but leaves the draggable DIV blank.

```
 var draggable = ui.draggable;                           
 var droppable = $(this);

  // Clear previous content
  $(this).empty();
  // Append new content
  $(this).append(draggable);


  // Clear previous content
  ui.draggable.empty();
  // Append new content
  ui.draggable.append(droppable);
```

I get the error below which relates to appending content into the draggable DIV

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element contains the parent.(…)

any ideas more than welcome !! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589606/jquery-draggable-items-lose-their-draggability-after-being-swapped-with-jsfiddl This question may help you out.

Comment: thats useful thanks, have now modified the formula and is working fine only issue is that the draggable DIV gets replaced correctly but has an additional parent div, I am trying appending childNode, etc with no joy yet...  here is the new formula I am using for swapping:

Comment: jQuery.fn.swapWith = function (to) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var copy_to = $(to).clone();
                    var copy_from = $(this).clone();
                    $(to).empty();
                    $(to).append(copy_from);
                    $(this).empty();
                    $(this).append(copy_to);
                });
            };

Comment: just managed to get rid of the additional DIV , here is the updated formula:  jQuery.fn.swapWith = function (to) {
                return this.each(function () {
                    var copy_to = $(to.html()).clone();
                    var copy_from = $(this).clone();
                    $(to).empty();
                    $(to).append(copy_from);
                    $(this).empty();
                    $(this).replaceWith(copy_to);
                });
            };

Comment: is using replaceWith to copy content into the draggable DIV

Answer (score 0):

just found that you can achieve drag and swap much more easily in angular by using .sortable() , thanks for your help Arun :)